# Searching and returning all occurences of keyword in a Postgres text column

Tags: sql, postgresql, confluence

**About database**

Database table for content of an Confluence page is named `bodycontent` and the HTML content is stored in column named `body`, which is a text field. Im using Postgres database. Primary key is named `bodycontentid`

**Result I need**

For each row in the table I need to find all occurence of `<image>` tag where `src` attribute starts with "http://images.mydomain.com/allImages/%" in the `body` column

**Example**

Let say that `body` with `bodycontentid` = 12345 contains following text:

```html
<h1>Chapter 1</h1>
<image src="http://www.google.com/image/111.jpg"/>
<h1>Chapter 2</h1>
<image src="http://images.mydomain.com/allImages/222.jpg"/>
<h1>Chapter 3</h1>
<image src="http://images.mydomain.com/allImages/333.jpg"/>
```

Result after running this query should return:

`bodycontentid`: 12345
`body`: http://images.mydomain.com/allImages/222.jpg

`bodycontentid`: 12345
`body`: http://images.mydomain.com/allImages/333.jpg

**What I have tried**

Im able to find all rows that has at least one occurence of the keyword Im searching for (see below), but what I need is to get list of all keywords per row that is matching my query.

```
SELECT *
FROM bodycontent
WHERE body LIKE '%http://images.mydomain.com/allImages/%'
```

Comment: [regexp_matches function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html), `regexp_matches(body, '<image src="(http://images.mydomain.com/allImages/[^"]*)', 'g')` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `regexp_split_to_table()` and then some string manipulation:

```
select bc.bodycontentid,
       left(rst.s, position('"' in rst.s) - 1) as domain
from bodycontent bc, lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(bc.body, E'srce="') rst(s)
where rst.s like 'http://images.mydomain.com/allImages/%';
```

Comment: Excellent! Works exactly as expected! Thanks a lot for quick reply!